# How do I clear geben call breakpoints?

Tags: debugging, emacs, xdebug, geben

Using emacs geben plugin, I've added breakpoints to my php application via the breakpoint menu: where `B` opens up a menu where you get to choose from

> 1) line 2) call ..., etc.

I've chosen `call` and added the function name to the list of breakpoints.

But unlike lines (where you can press `b` and `u` to set and unset a breakpoint respectively, the function call breakpoint just keeps breaking at that point. How do I get rid of the call breakpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in emacs, you can search for the entire list of key binds with `C-h b` (pressing `Ctrl+h` release and then press lowercase `b`), if you search (with `C-s`) you can find the Geben specific keybindings.

One of the bindings is:

```
d       geben-breakpoint-list-mark-delete
```

and

```
x       geben-breakpoint-list-execute
```

But these keybindings are for when you are in the `geben-breakpoint-list` view.

So to delete any breakpoint, open up the `geben-breakpoint-list` view (`C-c b` or in other words, `ctrl+c`, release, and then `b`).  Put your cursor at any breakpoint in that list, press `d` and a Capitalized "D" should appear by the breakpoint.  After flagging your breakpoints, press `x` to 'execute' the deletion of those breakpoints and they should remove themselves from the list.